# Surface integral of vector field $\vec{F}=\langle 2x^3,5xz^2,x^2+6y^2z \rangle$

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

I want to evaluate the surface intgeral of
$$\vec{F}=\langle 2x^3,5xz^2,x^2+6y^2z\rangle$$
in the $xy$-plane and $x^2+y^2\le4$.

I know I should use $$\iint_S\vec F\cdot d\vec{S}=\iint_S\vec F\cdot \vec nd\vec S.$$

**My approach:**

**(1)** Given this is in the $xy$-plane, then $z=0$ so $\vec r=\langle x,y,0\rangle$ and our boundary is $x^2+y^2\le4$.

**(2)** Next, $\vec F\cdot \vec n=\langle 2x^3,5xz^2,x^2+6y^2z\rangle\cdot\big(\langle 1,0,0\rangle\times \langle 0,1,0\rangle\big)=x^2+6y^2z$.

**(3)** And then, I was told that since $z=0$, I can just take the double integral:
$\int\int x^2dA$ over $x^2+y^2\le4$ which is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2(r\cos{\theta})^2rdrd\theta=4\pi.$$
My confusion comes from step **(3)**. Why are we able to say $6y^2z=0$ just because our boundary says that $z=0$? I mean, following the formula above, dotting $\vec F$ with $\vec n$ gives $x^2+6y^2z$, why do we integrate something else?

Comment: Because when you plug in a parametrization for a surface integral (the $\vec{r}(u,v)$ you chose $u=x$, $v = y$), what you are really integrating is $$\iint \vec{F}(\vec{r}(u,v)) \cdot (\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v)\:dudv$$ In other words the parametrization must be plugged in fully.

Comment: @NinadMunshi so we actually need to do $\vec F(\vec r(u,v))$ in the integrand why again?

Comment: The integrand is $x^2$ in polar coordinates and nothing else. The differential element $dA=r dr d\theta$

Comment: In this case, because the surface of integration is flat (disk with radius less than 4) this means that $dS=dA=dx dy=r dr d\theta$

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk I see that $dS=dA=dxdy=rdrd\theta$ but I'm still not seeing why we ignore $6y^2z$

Comment: Because $z=0$, as you said

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk I'm fully aware that I said $z=0$ **for the boundary**. I'm fully aware that $dS=dA=dxdy=rdrd\theta$.

Comment: The reason that we can let $z=0$ in the integral is that the vector field will satisfy that condition along that surface. Also, the condition $z=0$ is true for the entire surface and not just the boundary.

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk That makes more sense, thank you